# Plot sma on chart and RSI on a window below?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I am trying to plot the 120sma and the RSI. I want the sma on the chart and the RSI in a window below.

The problem I have is when I put overlay = true the RSI and the 120 sma display on the chart and its very messy and difficult to read.

If I set overlay = false it displays them both in a window below the price and still unreadable.

So How do I display the sma on the chart and the RSI on a window pane below.

I have tried the display = display.all and the other display options in the plot code.

```
strategy("My strategy", overlay= false, initial_capital = 10000, default_qty_type = "percent_of_equity", default_qty_value = 100)

rsi = ta.rsi(close, RSIInput) //get RSI
plot(rsi, color = color.orange) // Plot RSI

ExitMAPlot = ta.sma(close, ExitMA) // Get the MA
plot(ExitMAPlot, "Exit MA", color.red, 2, display = display.all)
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that. An indicator either runs on your main chart or in a separate pane. So, you need two indicators for that.